# Chrome js debug - two different values at the same time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

In the screenshot below you will see a console.log print of an object that has a `theme` field. But this field at the same time has and doesn't have a value. How to interpret this? My intent is to assign the value.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a property is filled asynchronously, or parent object is console logged before it's property is filled with value, such the behaviour will occur.

```
var obj = {};

// here when checking the dev tools obj = {}

ajax('url', function() {
 obj.a = 5
 // here when checking the dev tools obj = { a : 5}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Logging objects in Chrome is a bit tricky. If you do a log of the entire object and then change a property of the object, it always shows the latest value for the property.

Try logging Object.theme instead of logging the entire object and you will see the difference.

Comment: I understand that Chrome may change the object with the new value, but that doesn't explain why I have two different values.

Answer (score 0):

There is small blue icon on your screenshot, hover it and you get the answer to your question.