# Why my long decimal number is showing as "NaN" in javascript

Tags: javascript

Take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the last index of this array is shown as `"0.7713948369012206"` in console log.

But when I expend the array in console log, the 8th index is shown as `"NaN"`. It is effecting my code, Why it is not shown as a normal number?

My array is having thousands of object like this:

`array = {"abc": [0.7279141471991091, 0.7453059204457335, 0.7978668971106029, 0.6570360524074181, 0.7549066077622528, 0.7268105740052934, 0.7351847097682157, 0.7031287738185653, 0.7713948369012206] , "dsfs": [0.1454351471991091, 0.3054449204457335, 0.9353788971106029, 0.8570360524074181, 0.5549066077622528, 0.7268105740052934, 0.6351847097682157, 0.3031287738185653, 0.3523948369012206]}`

Comment: when I logged the `array` it showed ok for me...

Comment: Please include Browser name + version and which OS you are using

Comment: can you reproduce it in a snippet? copying your array from text will show correctly for us each time..

Comment: Browser name is Opera, and latest version. Windows 10

Comment: Let me try to reproduce, give me 5 min, my code is long, very long. I need to minimize it, to make it easy to understand.

Comment: I also tried it in chrome latest version, still same problem. @PeterB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mouse over the small blue `i` icon in the chrome console and you'll see a tooltip that explains this behavior. The variable is being evaluated when you click the spin-down triangle. The value of the array at index 8 is being changed between when you initially console.log and when you spin-down and inspect the values.

See: [Chrome js debug - two different values at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394673/chrome-js-debug-two-different-values-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Yeah, `value was evaluated just now`

Comment: But I am not sure, how that link solve my problem. What should I do? It is not just console.log. When I calculate the max value from array, the code always picks `NaN` was max value.

Comment: Somewhere in your code, after you `console.log` for the first time and the time when you click to spin-down the value, the value is getting set to NaN.

Comment: What do you mean by spin-down?

Comment: It's a term I've heard used to describe clicking on the little grey triangle to the left of the console output.

Comment: The triangle "spins down" and shows the detailed view.