# Why Java script object is different than it's individual property?

Tags: javascript, angular, object

I have a JS object where there is a attribute called value. After some kind of operation I am updating the value property of the object. Now I am facing a strange behavior as follow.

My code is like;

```
console.log(root.formElements[key][i]);             <-------- Line 1
console.log(root.formElements[key][i]["value"]);    <-------- Line 2
```

The lines of code is exactly one after another.

Now in chrome console I am getting the result as follow;

**For Line 1**

```
    {name: "campaignStartDate", label: "Campaign Start Date", type: "date", mandatory: "yes", icon: "event_note", …}
    class:"s4"
    classField:"startDate"
    icon:"event_note"
    label:"Campaign Start Date"
    mandatory:"yes"
    name:"campaignStartDate"
    newrow:"yes"
    type:"date"
    value:""
```

**For Line 2**

```
01/04/2018
```

**So the question is how is it possible when I am printing the object the value is blank but in next line if I print is individually the I am getting the value?**

The code snippet;

```
for (var key in root.formElements) {

    for(var i=0;i<root.formElements[key].length;i++)
    {
          root.formElements[key][i]["value"] = data[root.formElements[key][i]["classField"]];

          if(root.formElements[key][i]["name"] == "campaignStartDate")
          {
            console.log(root.formElements[key][i]);
            console.log(root.formElements[key][i]["value"]);
          }
    }
```

FYI I am facing this issue when I am developing an Angular 4 application. And In my application also I am getting the value property of the object is blank, when I am expecting the date string there.

Any help will be very good for me. Please let me know if any more data is required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `console` API does weird things, especially in Chrome.

Comment: No actually in my application also I am getting the value property blank.

Comment: @KOUSIKMANDAL Can you create a working snippet of your code so that we can see that behavior in plunker/jsfiddle etc? That would be easy to debug. From here don't know what are you getting in `root.formElements`

Comment: I'd guess that you overwrite it after that with the empty string you see in he log.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23392111/1048572

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mouse over the small blue `i` icon in the chrome console and you'll see a tooltip that explains this behavior. The variable is being evaluated when you click the spin-down triangle. The value of the object at index "value" is being changed between when you initially console.log and when you spin-down and inspect the values.

See: [Chrome js debug - two different values at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394673/chrome-js-debug-two-different-values-at-the-same-time)

Edit: Specifically, objects and arrays are evaluated when you click on them in the console. Strings (and other primitives) are evaluated when they are `console.log`ged.